# Can't get a simple toolbar functioning!

Tags: cocoa, xcode4

Extreme Objective-C/Cocoa noob.

Trying to follow Apple-eze about how to create a toolbar via interface builder but it's not working.  (XCode4)

Tossed the bar into the window in IB, arranged the possibles and the default set of items. I set the images for the 'image toolbar items', labels, palette labels, tags, priorities.  In XCode under identifier it says 'Auto-generated'.  Checked 'Autovalidates'.

Created a class. Added the IBAction and that's where understanding fails. Apple's "Creating a Toolbar in Interface Builder" document winds up with a short "Setting the Target, Action, and Toolbar delegate" section where nothing jibes.  My action appears nowhere in "Received Actions".  The example code I've seen does a lot of this programatically.

Answer (score 2):

- Is the class that handles the toolbar
  action declared as the nib file's
  owner?
- If not, are the methods in a class in the Responder chain? (probably not, but worth asking)
- Have you managed to set a delegate for the toolbar?

Comment: As the nib file's owner? No. How?   No responder chain.   Delegate? No.

Comment: Then what is the relationship of the class handling the toolbar's actions to the nib file that has the toolbar?

Comment: My _intent_ is simply to establish the connections necessary for Open and Save toolbar items to execute the methods in the class which will display the Open/Save panes but something fundamental is eluding me.  The toolbar is on the default template window in the nib the associated with the app delegate.

Comment: Are your IBActions showing up in the First Responder object (in the IB view) connect your outlets to that. This is what I meant by responder chain.

Comment: There you go. That's the same mechanism that the menu items use.

Comment: The toolbar item (and Open menu item) remains greyed out.

Comment: I can make it work by putting an instance of the class with the IBAction into the nib, but what if I don't _want_ it in there.  I can't figure out how make it active programatically.